# Envelopes get - how to get a Generic JSON Response

Tags: docusignapi

When using the DocuSign REST V2 API, doing a **GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}** returns an object with 24 properties, mostly URIs, IDs and timestamps.

The documentation for this call (https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/get/) in Examples section has a sub-section called "Get Status About a Specific Envelope " that shows this (24 properties), but it also has a sub-section called "Generic JSON Response" that has a lot more properties and data.

I would like to get a response like the "Generic JSON Response" but I cannot figure out how. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Generic JSON Response shows the response that would be returned for an envelope object that has every parameter/feature in use.

In addition, the Generic Response includes some secondary and tertiary data that may not be returned for the standard call.

What data do you want?

If you need an envelope's recipients, use the [EnvelopeRecipients::list](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/list/) method. If you want the envelope's documents, there is a separate call for that. Et cetera.

The problem is that returning everything known about an envelope would be a very expensive call for the platform to process. Therefore the data is provided to you in different calls.

Comment: The problem of not returning everything and making multiple calls is that this vendor has API request limits.

Comment: If your application is well behaved then there is no problem having the limit increased.